# Retaining Base Class Attributes in Dynamic Proxies

Tags: c#, .net, inotifypropertychanged, castle-dynamicproxy

I am using Castle DynamicProxy2.
Is it possible to tell proxy object to inherit attributes on its Base Class(proxied class) and attributes on Properities of Base class. 
If not possible in Castle. Any other library for this purpose??

I have posted source of problem here [Generic IPropertyChangedNotifier using Dynamic Proxy and wcf serialization problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053328/generic-ipropertychangednotifier-using-dynamic-proxy-and-wcf-serialization-proble)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider that these classes may not be appropriate for use in proxy classes.

This is also true for Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL classes - these serialize data from the base classes, making them platform-specific.

It's possible that you should create Data Transfer Objects corresponding to your Castle types, and then copy data into or out of them, and pass the DTO instances back and forth.